# How do I write a Makefile to link C code with Arm assembly code?

Tags: c, assembly, makefile, arm

The following terminal commands will compile and link my .c and .s files in linux

```
rm *.o
gcc -c printS.c -o printS.o
as lab8.S -o lab8.o
gcc lab8.o printS.o -o lab8test
```

I have never written a make file and I figure something like this deserves one. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827618/compiling-c-file-with-assembler-file-dependencies#4827835

Answer (score 1):

The same way you would make any make file. I am sure there are tons of examples out there and web pages.

```
ideally_the_result : dependencies
<tab>the commands
<tab>the commands
<tab>the commands
```

so

```
printS.o : printS.c
    gcc -c printS.c -o printS.o
```

And make a rule for each of the commands you are using.  I recommend you put the last one first so that it is the default if you dont have a command line option on make

also

```
clean : 
   rm -f *.o
   rm -f lab8test
```

to cover cleanup (make clean)

That is the super simple way that just works.  From there you can dig into all kinds of (make program specific, gnu make vs others) special characters that mean things to make more complicated rules.

Comment: This is very helpful. There are examples out there but i'm just not sure if it works differently when linking assembly files.

Comment: Think of makefiles as having nothing to do with compiling or linking, it is just a scripty language used to run programs.  The programs can be anything, dont have to be related to toolchains.  Could have a program parse an audio file that does an FFT and creates a gnuplot formatted data file, then another rule takes the data file and calls gnuplot to generate a png.